# How does this JWPlayer setup syntax work?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I’m a rather simple-minded JavaScript user, and the syntax for JWPlayer’s `setup` call intrigues me. It goes like this:

```
jwplayer('player_container').setup({
  "height"   : 360,
  "width"    : 640,
  "file"     : "https://xxxx.org/yyyy.mp4",
  "controls" : true,
  "autostart": true
});
```

where `player_container` is the ID of a `<div>` that will eventually contain the player code.

I don’t understand what’s going on here; there appear to be two sets of arguments being passed: `'player_container'` and an object. My guess is that there is a new instance of `jwplayer` being created and added to a JS “hash” with the index `"player_container"`, but that’s just a guess.

Can anyone enlighten me as to how this syntax can be interpreted?

Comment: `jwplayer('player_container')` calls a function that returns an object that has the `setup` method. `jwplayer(`…`).setup(`…`);` calls that method. The second argument is not a JSON string, by the way. It’s a simple object.

Answer (score 0):

This code could also be written as:

```
var player_instance = jwplayer('player_container');
player_instance.setup({
  "height"   : 360,
  "width"    : 640,
  "file"     : "https://xxxx.org/yyyy.mp4",
  "controls" : true,
  "autostart": true
});
```

The call to the jwplayer function creates an object, and setup is a method on that object. In JW Player's case, there are also other methods, like .on(...).